# Read the table data which has two foreign keys column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three tables called students,department,studentdepartment. 
**student table schema is**

```
student_id integer primary key ,student_name char
```

**department table schema is**

```
department_id integer primary key ,department_name char
```

**studentdepartment table schema is**

```
combo_id integer primary key,student_id integer,department_id integer,foreign key(student_id) references student,foreign key(department_id) references department
```

I am using backend is sqlite. Frontend is Python,Flask and SQL alchemy.

My questions is
**I tried to read some values from studentdepartment table.**
The format I used is

```
student_user = studentdepartment.query.all()
```

But **I am getting 'None' type as the result.**

But I have to read the table data.
can some one help me how to read the data from the table?

My models.py looks like this

```
from my_app import db
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column

class students(db.Model):
    "Adding the students" 
    students_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)   
    students_name = db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)
    students_email = db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)
    students_designation = db.Column(db.String(40),nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"students('{self.students_name}', '{self.students_email}','{self.students_designation}')"

class studentstimeslots(db.Model):
    "Adding the timing for students" 
    time_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)   
    students_id = db.Column(db.Integer,ForeignKey(studentss.students_id),nullable=False)    
    students_start_time = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)
    students_end_time = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"studentstimeslots('{self.students_id}', '{self.students_start_time}','{self.students_end_time}','{self.time_id}')"


class departments(db.Model):
    "Adding the department page"
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True,nullable=False)   
    department_role = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"departments('{self.department_id}','{self.department_role}')"

class studentdepartment(db.Model):
    "Combine department id and students ID"
    combo_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer,ForeignKey(departments.department_id))
    students_id = db.Column(db.Integer,ForeignKey(students.students_id))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"departmentstudents('{self.department_id}','{self.students_id}')"
```

My routes.py file looks like this

```
def editdepartment(department_id):
    "Editing the already existing department"
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Fetch the department name from the department table
        fetched_department_id = department_id
        getdepartment_name = department.query.filter(department.department_id==fetched_department_id).scalar()
        print(getdepartment_name,file=sys.stderr)
        #Fetch the student id based on the department id from the studentdeaprment  table
        get_department_details = departmentstudent.query.all()

        print(get_department_details,file=sys.stderr)
        return render_template("edit-departments.html")
```

Comment: `Query.all()` returns an empty list, not `None`, if there are no results. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes it's returning [None] like this.

Comment: It looks like you're using a mapped class and its `query` property, which means that the resulting list should either be empty, or a list of `studentdepartment` instances – not `[None]`. Please provide the minimal reproducible example. The linked help page has good pointers on how to come up with one. Ideally it should be something that's self contained, small enough to fit in a question, and runnable by others as is, so that we can verify your result.

Comment: Hi I have added some more code,can you check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the duplicate fields for student_id and for department_id in the studentdepartment. If a relationship
 - between student and studentdepartment as well
 - between department and studentdepartment
is needed than the code can look like this:

```
class student (db.Model):
  student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  student_name = db.Column(db.String(45))
  studentdepartments = db.relationship('studentdepartment', backref='student', 
     lazy=True, cascade="delete") 
class department (db.Model):
   department_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   department_name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
   studentdepartments = db.relationship('studentdepartment', backref='department', 
       lazy=True, cascade="delete")
class studentdepartment (db.Model):
   combo_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('student.student_id'))
   department_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('department.department_id'))
```

With such a model, creating objects and requesting studentdepartment looks like this:

```
s = student(student_name = "studentsamplename")
s1 = student(student_name = "studentsamplename1")
s2 = student(student_name = "studentsamplename2")
db.session.add(s)
db.session.add(s1)

d = department(department_name = "departmentsamplename")
d1 = department(department_name = "departmentsamplename1")

db.session.add(d)
db.session.add(d1)

sd = studentdepartment(student = s, department = d)
sd1 = studentdepartment(student = s1, department = d)
sd2 = studentdepartment(student = s2, department = d1)
db.session.add(sd)
db.session.add(sd1)
db.session.add(sd2)
db.session.commit()

studentdepartments = studentdepartment.query.all()
```

This prints the list of the studentdepartments.

The print delivers *[studentdepartment('1', '1','1'), studentdepartment('2', '1','2'), studentdepartment('3', '2','3')]* if you use the following in the model:

```
  def __repr__(self):
    return f"studentdepartment('{self.combo_id}', 
       '{self.department_id}','{self.student_id}')"
```

Comment: I tried doing this but getting [None] in the output

Comment: Thanks for adding more code to your example. You use "studentdepartment" in the model and "departmentstudent" in the query code?

Comment: If you are getting none with my code as well, then the problem is outside the code. The code works (tested).

Comment: After I add the data in the department and student table I can see only student_id and department_id  in studentdepartment table. When I tried this  "select * from studentdepartment where combo_id=1;" ,it's not returning anything.is this reason I am getting none in list,if yes how to solve this?

Comment: " I can see only student_id and department_id": if you only have these two fields in the def __repr__(self) and you make a print statement, then you only see these two fields.

Comment: BTW: If you don't have more than one studentdepartment object/relationship for a certain student and department, you can also delete the combo_id field from the studentdepartment model. Simply delete the combo_if field and add ", primary_key=True" for the remaining two foreign keys.

Comment: For your question why you don't see entries in the studentdepartment, I have added more code in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks,It worked and I made one more typo with primary key  while creating the schema,